# Редактирование определенных частей текста на python

Tags: python, текст

Мне необходимо сделать что бы скрипт на Python мог редактировать определенную строку из конфига. Допустим:

```
  {
    "name": "Insane Augewehr",
    "type": "Premium Workshop Augewehr Skin",
    "description": "Painted on his gun, the absolute madman!\n\n<color=#64c819>Workshop Contributors:\nDebski</color>\n\nWhen equipped this applies the <color=#64c819>Insane</color> appearance to the Augewehr in-game.",
    "name_color": "64c819",
    "itemdefid": 757,
    "marketable": false,
    "scraps": 0,
    "item_id": 1362,
    "item_skin": 170,
    "item_effect": 0,
    "vehicle_id": 0
  },
```

Из этой части конфига мне нужно допустим заменить item_id на 1200 и item_skin на 175. В конечном итоге должно выглядеть так:

```
  {
    "name": "Insane Augewehr",
    "type": "Premium Workshop Augewehr Skin",
    "description": "Painted on his gun, the absolute madman!\n\n<color=#64c819>Workshop Contributors:\nDebski</color>\n\nWhen equipped this applies the <color=#64c819>Insane</color> appearance to the Augewehr in-game.",
    "name_color": "64c819",
    "itemdefid": 757,
    "marketable": false,
    "scraps": 0,
    "item_id": 1200,
    "item_skin": 175,
    "item_effect": 0,
    "vehicle_id": 0
  },
```

Подскажите, как можно реализовать подобную замену через python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON можно обрабатывать через стандартный модуль `json`. Например, вы можете загрузить из файл-конфига данные и распарсить их модулем `json` в `dict`:

```py
import json

s = """{
    "name": "Insane Augewehr",
    "type": "Premium Workshop Augewehr Skin",
    "description": "Painted on his gun, the absolute madman!",
    "name_color": "64c819",
    "itemdefid": 757,
    "marketable": false,
    "scraps": 0,
    "item_id": 1362,
    "item_skin": 170,
    "item_effect": 0,
    "vehicle_id": 0
  }"""

d = json.loads(s)
print(d)
```

После загрузки, переменная `d` является словарём (dict) в котором можно менять значения стандартнми методами. После изменений, переменную `d` можно сохранить в файл.

Еще один вариант скрипта на Python:

```py
import re
import os


filename = './test.json'

# Открываем 2 файла, один читаем, в другой суффиксом .new пишем:
with open(filename, 'r') as fp1, open(filename + '.new', 'a') as fp2:
    for line in fp1:
        if line.find('item_id') > 0:       # Если встроке находится нужный параметр (подстрока)
            line = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '1200', line, 1)  # То меняем у этого параметра значение с помощью регулярного выражения
        elif line.find('item_skin') > 0:
            line = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '175', line, 1)

        fp2.write(line)

# Заменяем старый файл ./test.json содержимым из ./test.json.new
os.rename(filename + '.new', filename)
```

Comment: Да, хорошо, но мне необходимо редактировать строчки уже в готовом файле json. Допустим мы имеем файл settings.json в котором имеем строчку 
`"name": "Insane Weapon",` - нам нужно изменить именно её на любое другое название. Можете показать пример с подобными действиями?

Comment: @Slavatar - "изменить в готовом файле" - это и есть три шага - открыть файл, изменить в нём что-то и по новой ВЕСЬ файл сохранить (перезаписать). А вы как хотите? Изменить байты на определенной позиции в гигабайтном файле? Не знаю какая ФС такое позволяет. Обычные ФС умеют только дописывать (аппендить) в конец файла или перезаписывать его полностью насколько мне известно.

Comment: @Slavatar Какой вам пример нужен? Как открыть файл и прочитать его построчно или какой пример?

Comment: хах, ну примерно так и нужно. Необходимо скажем так, в тайне от пользователя изменить определенные строчки в конфиге. Конфиг не весит более 50, 30 или даже 20mb.

Comment: @Slavatar Добавил вариант. В комментариях пояснения.